# Android query, clickable list

Tags: android

Good evening.

Ive lately started making applications on Android (Im not too experienced) and id like to ask if something is possible.

I have used my own database already embed into my application and i want to make a search activity which through a listview adapter pastes my results into another screen as a list.

Now to the question. The list will contain only a few basic information on the record (ID and Name). Is there any way to make the items of the listview clicklable (automatically through the adapter) so that the user can click and be redirected to another screen where all the info of the record can be displayed and where he can possibly edit/add to the record?

P.S: Dont need the code just a general answer and possibly any helpfull links.

Thanks for your time..

Comment: Do you need `onItemClickListener`? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setOnItemClickListener%28android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener%29

Answer (score 1):

There are two things you need to look into. You need to look into clickable listviews items (onItemClickListener specifically). This will allow you to use whatever item was clicked and it's values.

The second thing you need to look at is passing information between activities. As your information is basic, it will be easy. Take a look at what I wrote here, it should help you:

[Android: Passing extra from one activity to another activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5819276/android-passing-extra-from-one-activity-to-another-activity/5819452#5819452)

I hope this helps.